# How to pass token to requirements.yaml used by ansible galaxy for installing pre-requisites

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use an environment variable inside of requirements.yml but it's not working

```
    - src: 'http://oauth2:{{ lookup("env", "GITLAB_TOKEN") }}@gitlab.repo/data-migration.git'
  scm: git
  version: "master"
```

The token is a sensitive data , I can't put it in requirenments.yaml, any idea please ?

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yaml --force
```

ansible --version = 2.4.6.0

Comment: you want to clone the gitlab project via ansible, right ? You can pass the token during execution in extra vars and also there is a module gitlab_project available in ansible why are you using src ?

Comment: My roles and playbook are in separate git repositories, so in my playbook code i added a requirements.yaml to checkout roles using by playbook (I use ansible-galaxy install -f requirements.yaml to install roles before ansible-playbook command )

Answer (score 0):

To debug:

run a command -->

```
export TOKEN=test
```

playbook -->

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: play
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('env', 'TOKEN') }}"
```

output -->

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}
```

The lookup should work for replacements.

```
- src: "http://oauth2:{{ lookup('env', 'TOKEN') }}@gitlab.my-repo.git"
  name: role1
  version: master
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it's not work with ansible 2.4.6

Comment: Can you update the question with steps ? It has worked for me earlier. Update the question with the steps you took I will execute at my end

Comment: You are in ansible 2.4 ?

Comment: nope, I am on ansible 2.7.8. I have used in earlier version as well. prior to 2.4.6 I am editing the answer for debugging the value using debug module. kindly run that playbook and check

Answer (score 0):

The `--token` parameter can be used in the ansible-galaxy command for installing roles from private repos.

So your `requirements.yml` could look like: (note that I took the liberty of making this http**s**)

```yaml
roles:
  - src: 'https://gitlab.repo/data-migration.git'
    scm: git
    version: "master"
```

and your installation command would become:

```
ansible-galaxy role install --token $GITLAB_TOKEN -r requirements.yml --force
```

Now if you want to do this from github actions (my current problem)... brace yourself

Comment: Did you manage to get it working from inside of a github workflow? I'm running into exactly the same issue.